# How to make custom field from django field

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to make my custom field extend from django foreign key.

```
class CustomField(models.ForeignKey):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.type=kwargs.pop('type', None)
      super(CustomField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I am using like

```
CustomField('User', type="test")
```

This works correctly but i want to hard code model name in my field like this

```
super(CustomField, self).__init__('User', *args, **kwargs)
```

so that i can use

```
CustomField(type="test")
```

but then i get this error

```
__init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'to'
```

Comment: It should work, are you sure you are calling `CustomField(type="test")`? What is the content of `args` and `kwargs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your are sending the `to` parameter used by models.ForeginKey in `self` and in the 'User' parameter when you make call `super(CustomField, self).__init__('User', *args, **kwargs)`. You can try to do in this way:

```
class CustomField(models.ForeignKey):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['to'] = 'User'
        self.type = kwargs.pop('type', None)
        super(CustomField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```